# how to reset gnome panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

I think my gnome-panel is messed up because I alt+right click it and nothing pops up.  I'm on 12.04, classic gnome desktop.

so I used `locate` and found gnome-panel in .gconf somewhere, how do I clear just gnome-panel's settings so that I can add things to my panel again?

edit:

```
matt: ~/.gconf $ find|grep -iw panel
./desktop/ibus/panel
./desktop/ibus/panel/%gconf.xml
./apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel
./apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/%gconf.xml
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Config reset**

This worked for me in GNOME Classic on 12.04 to reset the gnome-panel configuration:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
killall gnome-panel
```

Run the commands in a terminal or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>.

**Popup menu**

Try
<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-rightclick
to get the popup menu.

Comment: Still works great with gnome-session-flashback.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and paste:

`gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel`

and

`killall gnome-panel`

Or you can manually delete the folder ~/.gconf/apps/panel/

`mkdir ~/gnomepanelbackup ; mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/gnomepanelbackup`

this will create backup of current settings in home directory. then,

`killall gnome-panel`

Reference: [1](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/how-to-reset-gnome-panels-compiz.html).

Comment: hmm it looks the same ["show desktop" on left and "workspace switcher" on right], and I **still** cannot alt right-click and add to panel.

Comment: Then you could try to manually delete the configuration folder ~/.gconf/apps/panel

Comment: Ok that's the problem there is none, check the question again.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at other posts and tried:

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

It didn't work.  But then I tried this, and bingo!

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
killall gnome-panel
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while transferim gnome-terminal settings from one machine to another.

My solution was copying related files and then kill gconfd-2 daemon

```
cp -r /tmp/backup/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/ ~/.gconf/apps/
killall gconfd-2
```

If you don't kill gconfd-2 changes aren't applied until you logout.

Answer (score 0):

Should works with every desktop managers, gnome, mate, etc. Does not block the current shell.

```
killall $DESKTOP_SESSION-panel && $DESKTOP_SESSION-panel </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```