# network icon disappeared in gnome-panel

Tags: gnome, icons, gtk, gnome-panel

Today I dragged a photo to the gnome-panel.Then the panel background changed,but after a reboot i got an error saying "reload gnome-panel". I reloaded, but it asked 10 times. After that my network applet is not disappeared in the gnome-panel.

I tried

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

and dragged the network applet icon but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having to completely reconfigure your panel, you could try to reset it:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/
killall gnome-panel
```

I refer to this thread: [how to reset gnome panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125662/how-to-reset-gnome-panel) where i found the quoted command.