# GNOME launcher and settings dissappeared

Tags: gnome, launcher

After a reboot the launcher or dock on the left vanished and hitting the super key  no longer brings the launcher, search or focus back again. OI tried reinstalling tweak tools but it doesn't work any more it seems like my GNOME broke :/
I am used to this behaviour how can I bring it back? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! **;-)** What version of Ubuntu and GNOME are you running? And are you then not able to access the Activities Overview at all? Or are you, but just there is nothing there? Please provide more information to better help us help you.

Comment: Something removed my gnome-shell because I typed --version and nothing occurred. I installed via sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Now it says  GNOME Shell 3.10.4  but the launcher doesn't appear.

Comment: NO activities or recent applications showed here, no place to search as it used to be either. I hit the super key and nothing.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 14.04 sorry.

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125662/how-to-reset-gnome-panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch a terminal with a hotkey :

```
CTRL + ALT + T
```

Install aptitude and reinstall gnome-shell

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude reinstall gnome-shell
```

For the next step you'll need to go to another place on the desktop and it can work to run the previous steps in case the hotkey doesn't work

```
CTRL + ALT + F1
```

You'll be presented with a login on the terminal. 
Type your user name and provide the password for your account

Finally reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Edit :

I think "sudo" doesn't find the reboot command in that case do :

```
sudo su (you will be asked for root password)
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that and the normal behavior didn't came back. NO super key or launcher working yet. I must clarify I didn't played with the tweak tool or something odd it was just a reboot after updates.

Comment: Then Gnome-Shell could not be broken and something else could be  happening.

In the meantime you may consider using another launcher. There's **Gnome-Do** which works similarly with the hotkey _Super + Spacebar_

Comment: Thanks, I tried several things in the meantime.After doing your step by step fix I noticed the login changed (with my custom profile image).
 I just logout to try something else (I tried mapping the keyboard or the super key) and noticed an advanced option in the login and used login as GNOME (I was login as GNOME metacity before since the option of plain/pure GNOME disappeared after the odd reboot) and it worked fine. Maybe it was a mix of the missing GNOME you helped me to fix and being lockout of the pure GNOME at the login.

Comment: Where can I learn to map stuff and bananas ? XD @AndrésParada

Comment: I didn't get the expression, I just used the thick to mark as answered because I didn't know about that, sorry.

Comment: @AndrésParada ok, you can unmark it too